# Pcross-like, nonogram-like in near-linear time

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I have a problem with a puzzle game like pcross in which I have a nxn square: At any index of rows and columns I have an integer that say the maximum numbers of points that I can place in that row/col. The question is Exist an algorithm that tells me the maximum number of placed points (no interest where they are exactly placed) that runs in linear time? and what is?

Comment: i don't understand your question. what are the placed points?

Comment: If you see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_tomography the problem is right that. Now the question is: exists an algorithm that say me the maximum number of admissible point (according to the rule) that runs in linear or near-linear time? I see erdos-gallai but works only with one sequence of integers. In this case I have two sequence (row and col) and they are bipartite.

Comment: so like http://www.conceptispuzzles.com/index.aspx?uri=puzzle/pic-a-pix; but the problems there have a unique solution, and you want to know given U,V vectors how many solutions there are?